# Returning object from a function

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, oop

If an object is created inside a function and the function returns that type of oject how is the memory handled.

Example:

```
Public Function GetEmployee(employeeid as integer) as employee

Dim oEmployee as new employee
oEmployee.FirstName="Bob"
...
...

return oEmployee
end function
```

Does the variable that receive the object still a pointer to the memory location that was used inside the function?

What about when you do a `oEmployee2=oEmployee`

Is oEmployee2 just a pointer? And any changes to oEmployee will now affect the other.  Just trying to understand it from a memory perspective and how that scope works

Thanks

Comment: read up on reference vs value types in C#, e.g. here: http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming oEmployee is a reference type (not a struct), if you pass it as an argument, then you are passing the reference. In .NET you should think in terms of Reference types vs Value types.

This article really helped me understand how memory is allocated when I was starting out.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rmcochran/csharp_memory01122006130034PM/csharp_memory.aspx

Comment: Page 2 of that article deals with your concerns about passing objects as parameters

Comment: Why is this marked as an answer when the question was to do with VB and the answer is about C#?

Comment: My answer isn't to do with c# only. Are you talking about the linked article? It focuses on .NET memory management, not c#.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `employee` is a *reference type* (e.g. any class) the method will return a reference (similar in concept to a pointer in unmanaged languages) to the object instance (usually on the heap). Since only one object instance exists, all changes to it will affect the instance.

If `employee` is a *value type* (e.g any struct or primitive type) a separate copy of the instance is returned.